# Websocket with AngularJS/Asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, websocket

I had a specific questin about angularjs with websocket.  I currently have an application that utilizes a websocket to communicate with a server, this is all nice and dandy - and when I move around pages in angular the websocket persists throughout all of the routes which is neat.  Unfortunately the problem is that if the user refreshes the page (for some dumb reason), the websocket disconnects.  I was wondering what the best method of handling this is.  Should I just have an alert when the user tries to refresh, can I somehow detect that the websocket is closed when the page is refreshed and start a new one?  I'm just wondering what the best practice for something like this is. 
Thanks

Comment: The connection will end, nothing you can do about it. But why not just restart it?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do, if the user refreshes, it is like restarting an application, all the bootstrapping happens again and connections are created again.

You can use [javascript:onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) to warn the user that if refreshes or leaves he will lose the connection. But your users will hate your for that, it is very annoying.

Consider as well, that the user may open several tabs.

Starting a new connection is the best way. Just make sure that the user can somehow recover his context. If there is a different context per tab, then you will have to put a connectionID parameter in the URL to persist it through refreshes, and if the context is per user session, then a cookie with the session ID will do.